# Authenticate MVC clients with Web API Tokens

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently I have created a WebAPI Project using identity framework and I have setup tokens to be returned when authenticating with the API.

So now I am looking at creating a standalone MVC application that will allow the user to make calls to the WebAPI to get back end data.

The goal is to separate functionality so that other applications can also start interacting with back end data through web calls.

So the confusion now is how do I setup my MVC project so that I can use the Authorize attributes on controllers with the token received from the WebAPI.  I think I need to enable bearer tokens in the ConfigureAuth method in Startup.Auth.cs.  However will that be sufficient enough?  Or do I also need to enable the cookie authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC and Web Api are fundamentally different when it comes to authentication. With Web Api, the bearer token has to be set in the header of the request, but this is not an issue as all API requests are done programmatically by the client, i.e. there's human-intervention involved in setting up the client to authenticate the request properly.

MVC is a different beast in that the actions are accessed generally via a web browser, which will not automatically affix a bearer token to the request header. What it *will* do is pass cookies set by the server back to the server. That's why cookie auth is used most typically for MVC web applications.

What you should do is enable cookie auth for the MVC site and then set up your sign in action to authenticate via the Web Api. When you get back a valid auth from the Web Api, then you can manually sign in the user via the Identity API:

```
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user);
```

Comment: Ok makes sense.  So then to leverage Authorize attributes just request & store claims and roles after login in that same cookie?

Comment: Essentially, yes.

Comment: I also would have to create a new instance of instance of ApplicationSignInManager, ApplicationUserManager?  But I don't want to create a new instance of DbContext because I don't want to communicate with an Identity Db directly.  Only through API Calls.

Comment: That's unavoidable. In short, you can't factor the DB completely out of an MVC app if you intend to use Identity. To rely solely on the Web Api, you would essentially have to build your own auth system. Or, you might be able to find a third-party system that might be able to work with a Web Api. Identity is out of the question, though.